# Using component of one module as path in route of app module

Tags: angular

I have simple module SomeOtherModule and i want that it's **CounterComponent** is available as path in AppModule.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CounterService } from '../services/counter.service';
import { CounterComponent } from '../counter/counter.component';
@NgModule({  
  imports: [ CommonModule],
  providers: [CounterService],
  declarations: [  CounterComponent ],
  exports: [CounterComponent] 
})
export class SomeOtherModule { }
```

and AppModule:

```
import { SomeOtherModule } from './some-other/some-other.module';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       AppComponent,  
       HomeComponent,     
       CounterComponent, 
    ],
    imports: [SomeOtherModule,
         RouterModule.forRoot([
          { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent }, 
     ]
)]
```

TS error on CounterComponent not found

Comment: You could specify your component path in a `SomeOtherRoutingModule` an then redirect 'counter' to the `SomeOtherModule` from the `AppModule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AppModule`, remove `CounterComponent` from `declarations` module property. He is already declared on`SomeOtherModule`.

EDIT: I don't know if you cut it for the question, but if not, you forgot to import `CounterComponent` in your `AppModule` files.

Comment: Neither works. I cut BrowserModule for simplicity as AppModule  has 20+ dependencies

Comment: @ВладимирЛапенков Okey, my bad. In your `AppModule`, did you import `CounterComponent` ?

Comment: No. I thought it belongs to another module so i don't need to explicit import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';

Comment: @ВладимирЛапенков import from ES and import from NgModule are totally differents. If you write `component: CounterComponent` explicitly on `AppModule`, then, you need to import `CounterComponent`. Just try it :) if I wrong, I will learned something

Comment: You mean i should import CounterComponent in @NgModule of AppModule?

Comment: No, your `AppModule` file should contains this line : `import { CounterComponent } from '.......' `

Comment: You are right. If i comment SomeOtherModule in NgModule imports i get  Error: Component CounterComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module. So i have to explicitly import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component'; and this is correct